# Is the percentage of CPU utlized by the .NET garbage collector an indicator of anything?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection, clr

As an explanation for the slowness of an application, someone reported that the garbage collector, during collection, was taking up 17% of the CPU. To me, that statistic sounded irrelevant since 17% is not too much to worry anyway. Besides, it is an arbitrary metric that tells me nothing about the constitution of the process' memory.

What would be more relevant data to me would be things like:

1. How many Gen 2 collections did we have?
2. Show me the memory dump and let me party with it and come back to you. Let me look at the heapstat (`!dumpheap -stat` from psscorX), syncblocks, etc.
3. Show me the CPU utilization during a heavy period of slowness so I know it's not an I/O bound issue that's begging the introduction of asynchrony into the desgin.
4. How many garbage collections did we have since we launched suspect operation and how many of them were full collections?
5. Show me the LOH heap fragmentation.
6. Show me the unmanaged heap, the free space in the process and the total space occupied by the managed heap.
7. Profile the code and see what's taking time. Then zero in on the operation that's taking the most amount of time.

But the CPU utilization held by a run of garbage collection? That doesn't seem like a relevant metric to me at all.

So, I ask for a confirmation.

1. Is that metric of CPU utilized by the GC, esp. when it is only 17%, a relevant indicator of problems in the application?
2. Is there an expected threshold CPU utilization that the GC should normally fit within so as to be considered a normal collection of a nice and healthy application?

We're talking about a process run on a workstation version of the CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage collection is a by-product of memory allocation.
If garbage collection takes 17% of CPU time, that indicates that memory allocation overall takes a larger fraction, like maybe 34%.
(Of course, if your program is I/O bound, CPU% is less important.)

One common way for programs to be slow (or to put it in positive terms, a common way to speed up programs) has to do with memory allocations that could be avoided.
I use the [*random pausing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) method of pinpointing these opportunities.

[*This link*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302345/2429) explores one example where pooling and re-using objects, rather than always allocating new ones, was one of the large speedups.
What always seems to need to be said is that programs typically have *more than one* way to be made to go faster, so performance tuning can go in stages.
So, suppose you are spending 34 out of 100 seconds of time right now on memory allocation, and suppose you could remove 30 of those. Then the time shrinks to 70 seconds, for a speedup of 100/70 = 1.43x.
Now there is almost certainly something else (not necessarily memory allocation) taking 20 seconds. It was 20/100 = 20%, but after fixing the first problem it is more; it is 20/70 = 29%.
It got bigger proportionally by the first speedup.
Fixing it gives a speedup of 70/50 = 1.4x.
If you have multiple problems and you fix them one at a time, their speedup factors multiply together and can be quite dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found some information on this topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx#Issue_HighCPU).

It appears that checking the CPU utilization during a collection may give one some insight into whether too many or too frequent a number of collections are taking place. This could mean that objects are being allocated too quickly and/or are not being freed up, i.e. are living too long (for example too many class level objects), and therefore it is taking the garbage collector longer as there is not much to collect in every collection.

I reproduce the relevant snippet from the article:

[Garbage Collection and Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx#Issue_HighCPU) -> [Issue: CPU Usage During a Garbage Collection Is Too High](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx#Issue_HighCPU)

> CPU usage will be high during a garbage collection. If a significant
>   amount of process time is spent in a garbage collection, the number of
>   collections is too frequent or the collection is lasting too long. An
>   increased allocation rate of objects on the managed heap causes
>   garbage collection to occur more frequently. Decreasing the allocation
>   rate reduces the frequency of garbage collections.
>
> You can monitor allocation rates by using the Allocated Bytes/second
>   performance counter. For more information, see [Performance Counters in
>   the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e.aspx).

This, however, makes no comment on whether or not the 17% CPU utilization is high, as it shouldn't. It does provide a lead with the suggestion that we look into the allocation per second performance metric and the `% Time` counter.